# Logback SMTPAppender Not Working with multiple errors

Tags: smtp, logback

When I log two errors at the same time:
e.g

```
log.error("error1");
log.error("error2");
```

I get two messages for error1 (with cyclic buffer size set to 1) or two messages for error2 when cyclic buffer size is the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in the latest Logback version 1.1.3